# Can I get access to ExecuteQueryAsync without Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sharepoint

I'm working on a service that connects to Sharepoint to retrieve data. I would like to make this as asynchronous as possible.

However, it looks like the [Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585) `Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client` for use with standard .NET doesn't come with any asynchronous functionality. Case in point is the `ExecuteQuery` function, which does have an overload `ExecuteQueryAsync` but that is only found in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Silverlight.dll` or `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Phone.dll` as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/jj168848(v=office.15).aspx) states.

Is there any way to access this asynchronous functionality somehow? I'm not sure if I can just try using the Silverlight dll straight up in my code, or if that would cause problems later down the road. Pretty sure it will. Are there any other APIs that will allow me to do the things I want to do?

Comment: If you have option do it using jquery/javascript,It is also available in Sp.Js

Comment: @vinayakhegde that is unfortunately impossible. It will have to be done with the C# API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper to make this task asynchronous using `TaskCompletionSource`

To wrap this

```
public override void ExecuteQueryAsync(
    ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler succeededCallback,
    ClientRequestFailedEventHandler failedCallback
)
```

You'd provide this as an extension method:

```
public static class ClientExtension
{
  public static async Task<bool> ExecuteQueryAsync(this ClientContext ctx)
  {
     TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
     ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync(
        (s, e) => t.SetResult(true),
        (s, e) => t.SetException(e.Exception));
     return tcs.Task;
  }
}
```

To call this, you can apply

```
await client.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Comment: You're missing the question here. This is what I _would_ do if I had `ExecuteQueryAsync` available at all in the API. I don't. The question here is if there is some way that I can get any async functionality in the managed object model.

Comment: What's the signature of the synchronous API call?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same and all i found was an extension method
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/738008/programming-efficiently-with-the-sharepoint-client#async

```
public static class CSOMExtensions
{
    public static Task ExecuteQueryAsync(this ClientContext clientContext)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a link to a post by me. I've since created a new version. The above simply moves execution to a new thread which is fine for eg. desktop applications to move execution off the UI thread. It is no good for web applications. Have a look at my answer for an update.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Online CSOM assemblies have now been updated to include ExecuteQueryAsync. However, there isn't one for On-Premise (2013, 2016 or 2019).

I have a public gist containing an implementation of ExecuteQueryAsync: https://gist.github.com/johnnycardy/9e1671cf5087dcd8f4e7892fc3c2cfb8

Then instead of calling `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()`, you can do `await CSOM15ExecuteAsync(clientContext);`.